# Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc'

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

I've researched all similar questions but noone solves my problem.

When I build the project, then gives error like below;

```
Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.    App_WebReferences/ProcessWSReference/
```

I also setupped `Crystal Reports`
and developing a 64 bit machine, VS 2012, .Net 4.0, IIS 6.0

Comment: In my experiences with Crystal, it uses the GAC heavily. I would check in `C:\Windows\assembly` and see if you have `CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc` with the exact version number available in there.

Comment: @StevenV Nope, It's not the same version. How to equalize?

Comment: You say you've installed Crystal Reports, but obviously ensure you've got the correct version installed with all the updates installed. After that you can either edit the version number in your web.config, or look into assembly redirection.

Comment: this project has been using an older version of crystal report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've installed this dll then problem solved!
http://tcsoftware.net/blog/2011/05/crystal-reports-redistributable-download-net-2005/

Comment: After installing the above version of Crystal Reports perform restart of 'Visual Studio IDE 20xx'

Answer (score 1):

If you're using more recent than 2005 version of visual studio, you can download installers here: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

"install executable" column is to install Crystal Reports integration with Visual Studio (2012, 2013)

MSI 32\64 is the runtime needed in the server where you will deploy your application.